# The inequality is true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

The following inequality

$$(*) \quad \frac{x}{\sinh(x)} \leq  e^{-x}, \quad \forall x>0$$
or
$$(**) \quad \frac{x}{\sinh(x)} \leq  e^{x}, \quad \forall x>0$$
are true ?

thank you in advance

Comment: The latter is true.

Comment: Ok thanks @ Akiva Weinberger

Comment: $$\frac{x}{\sinh x}\leq\frac{6}{6+x^2}$$ is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you provide no context, I'll simply answer the question: no, it's not. Try substituting $x=1$ and the inequality won't be satisfied.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2F+(sinh(1))+-+e%5E(-1)

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$ and $x/\sinh x\leq e^{-x}$ then $x\leq (1-e^{-2x})/2<1/ 2,$ but this  is clearly false when $x\geq 1/2.$